# A question on AWS RDS Multi-AZ downtime when changing the Instance type

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, multi-az

I have an RDS Database serving a production application.

The RDS DB is a db.m3.large and is Multi-AZ Instance Deployment. (Role is "Instance" in the console).

I've been informed by AWS that I have to migrate my Database from an M3 instance to one of the newer types this time next month. This is the first time I have had to touch this Database on the hardware side for quite a while so I would like some validation on my understanding on how best to approach this.

I am aware there is documentation but its a bit vague and I would like a statement in laymans terms.

My current approach/understanding on how to handle this would be:

1. I modify the instance type
2. While the instance type is modifed, failover occurs and the traffic is redirected to a standby instance to handle traffic while the changes are modified
3. The failover will occur from between 60-120 seconds, so that would be the expected amount of downtime.
4. Once the job is done, the traffic is redirected to original primary instance

Comment: I would recommend that you take a snapshot of the DB, and run it in the new instance type first. In my experience, anything unexpected can happen when you do something that you've never done before in the production environment. The 60-120s downtime that you described is the best situation. You really need to expect at least 10 minutes of downtime if everything goes well.